# How to get count of items in the columns of dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataframe as follows:

```
data2 = {
    'values': ['associated with autism spectrum disorder', 'Autism', 'High-functioning autism'],
    'Genes': ['GRIN3A, PRKAG1, GRIN2', 'CNTNAP2', 'CNTNAP2'],
    'Group':['Autism', 'Autism', 'Autism']
}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
```

df2

```
    values                                      Genes                   Group
0   associated with autism spectrum disorder    GRIN3A, PRKAG1, GRIN2   Autism
1   Autism                                      CNTNAP2                 Autism
2   High-functioning autism                     CNTNAP2                 Autism
```

I want to get the count of items in df['Genes'].
i tried:

```
data2 = {
    'values': ['associated with autism spectrum disorder', 'Autism', 'High-functioning autism'],
    'Genes': ['GRIN3A, PRKAG1, GRIN2', 'CNTNAP2', 'CNTNAP2'],
    'Group':['Autism', 'Autism', 'Autism']
}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
```

df2

but i get following results with unwanted data in it:

```
Group    Genes                                  Count
Autism   [GRIN3, A, PRKAG1, GRIN2, C, CNTNAP2]  6
```

[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68569196/how-to-get-unique-elements-and-their-counts-in-each-category-from-a-dataframe/68569335#68569335)
Count is supposed to be 4 but I get 6 and `A` and `C` in the data.

Comment: What did you try, and what's the end result you expect?

Comment: @ThePyGuy
`dfs= df2.groupby('Group').agg({'Genes':lambda x: set(x.str.split(', ').explode())}).reset_index()
dfs['count'] = dfs['Genes'].apply(len)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dfs= df2.groupby('Group').agg({'Genes':lambda x: set(x.str.split(', ').explode())}).reset_index()
dfs['count'] = dfs['Genes'].apply(len)
```

dfs

```
    Group    Genes                              count
0   Autism   {CNTNAP2, GRIN2, GRIN3A, PRKAG1}   4
```